# Redirecting to https for any URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

In my .htaccess file, I have the below.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

This works fine until someone goes to http://www.example.com/test because that does not force a redirect to https.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your rules actually. Do you have something cached? The first condition takes care of anything that is `http` so it will get that one too. Your rule is actually correct for all cases. You can even test the rule [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change your last two lines to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.example\.com|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```